# Javascript add class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add class to a link when it is clicked

Here is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#block-block-23 li a').click(function() {
     jQuery('#block-block-23 li a').addClass("selected");

   });
   });
```

and  the problem is 
    The class is adding when clicking the link but when the page loads it is automatically gets removed.i have tried the toggleClass() function also

Comment: When the page load / reload it will apply original attributes to the elements.

Comment: How to solve this? I want the class to be added permanently until the next link is clicked.

Comment: Is the link part of navigation? do you load another page on link click or same one.

Comment: You could use server side logic to apply the class on page load.

Comment: yes it is a part of navigation. i am loading another page on click

Comment: How about setting active link "class" on the web server itself? When you want to do something like this I would rather do it on the webserver than on the javascript. Hope this helps.

Comment: Simply you cant. but you have one chance with cooookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my Prob with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#block-block-23 li a").each(function(){
   if(jQuery(this).attr('href') == (location.pathname)){
     jQuery(this).addClass('active');
   }
});  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when page is loaded it will load the original content so your click event code will not loaded.

What you can do is manually trigger click event on page load.

**Example**

```
jQuery('#block-block-23 li a').trigger('click');
```

**Complete Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery('#block-block-23 li a').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#block-block-23 li a').addClass("selected");
    });

    jQuery('#block-block-23 li a').trigger('click');
});
```

**Optimize Code**

```
jQuery("#block-block-23 li a[href='+location.pathname+']").each(function()
{
```

Comment: That would load the page again, hence removing any modiefied content, infinite loop.

Comment: ohhhh...Yes i need to pass event as argument.....one second i am editing it.

Comment: @ФейсалСайед edited....see now

Comment: `preventdefault()` will prevent the page from reload? does OP want that? if that is the case then second trigger is nod needed any more. also you need to put `preventdefault()` in click event.

Comment: @ФейсалСайед well why don't we let OP to say about this..?

Comment: I asked him that question, waiting for his answer. plus was not criticizing, just informing.

Comment: @ФейсалСайед Yes I am appreciate that...and i also just saying because we do not know what OP doing so its worth to discuss about it.

Comment: Solved my prob with the following codejQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#block-block-23 li a").each(function(){
   if(jQuery(this).attr('href') == (location.pathname)){
     jQuery(this).addClass('active');
   }
});  

});

Comment: @DinkaranIlango well thats great...+1 for you

Comment: @DinkaranIlango well you can still improve your code by using my edited answer code....because `.each` loop will certainly effect performance.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two scenarios...

1. The application is multi-page.

In that case you can hard code the class in another page.

1. The application is single-page and the link is only for decoration purpose.

In that case you can prevent the default behavior of the link.

```
jQuery('#block-block-23 li a').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: How will it addClass on page load ?